# Sample Barcode Scanner App does not work in android

Tags: icenium

I tried to run the sample barcode scanner example provided with icenium. 
The ios build works well, but I get an error when running the android build.

[Web Console] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'barcodeScanner' of undefined:33

The ios version I am testing on is ios 7.1.
The android version is 4.1.2.

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova 3.2 support has been added in the latest version of Icenium and the BarcodeScanner plugin has been updated to its latest version which complies with Cordova 3.2 as well. If you have cloned the BarcodeScanner sample prior the 3.2 release, please clone it again and it would work out of the box in both Android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Cloned the project again - the issue still remains. The properties screen shows the version as 1.1.0 for ios & android. cordova version is 3.2.0

Comment: We've tested on several Android devices including two with 4.1.2, but cannot reproduce the issue. Please open the main.js file and make sure that the barcodescanner plugin is invoked like this: cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner

Comment: Yes, the call is cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(...). I do not think the javascript call is the problem. The same code works on ios. It could be a device specific issue. The device is a Samsung Galaxy Victory (SPH-L300) - not sure if that will help.

Comment: We do not have this specific device at our disposal to test with, but as mentioned previously, it does work on all Android devices in our local tests. In fact, this is the first report of a device which has problems running the sample.